# Calling an LWC component inside another component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Greetings......

I have a question/doubt which I would like to clear. And
I'm new to the Salesforce world so forgive me if it's a foolish question.

Let's say i have component A for Account, B for User and C for Lead. And i wanted display details for these objects.
We can hardcode it and display the details, but i want to know is there any way to make a component (let's say component D) so when I call the component D inside A it will automatically detect it's for Account and display the details. Similarly for the other components. So basically what I'm saying is dynamic search functionality, so is there any way to do it? If there is a way then please explain it with an example.

Thank you

And Sorry for the title, i wasn't sure what to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, parent components give their child components data. In your case, D would accept some data:

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class D extends LightningComponent {
  @api record;
}
```

Which the other components could provide data for:

```
<c-d record={record}></c-d>
```

This is how components are built; child components accept data from parent components to render themselves, and parent components accept events from child components to react to changes in the child.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox for the explanation.... So In my example we need to send Object API name to the component D from component A to display related details.

Comment: @NARAYAN correct.